# Redux Thunk Submit to Action

Tags: reactjs

I been stuck to this quite a bit, I am trying to pass in my state to the redux but it seems like I am doing it wrong.

This are my code:

This is my submit function

```
 popForm() {
    let states = this.state.orders;
    let d = states.filter((data) => {
      return data !== null && data !== undefined
    });
    // console.log("d",d);


    this.props.LogInClick(d);
    // LogInClick(state);
  }
```

This is my mapToDispatch

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    LogInClick : (data) => dispatch(Actions.addDynamic(data)),
  }
}
```

Action call

```
export const addDynamic = ({data}) => {
    console.log("Manage to get to here");
    console.log("dataInAction",data);

}
```

My reducer

```
case Actions.ADD_DYNAMIC: {
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your synchronous action [should to return an object](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) with `type` and `payload`.

When dealing with async actions, you need thunk(or saga etc) middleware. Your code seem to dispatch normal action (not async). So just make sure that your action returns type and payload.

**Like this**

```js
export const addDynamic = ({data}) => {
    console.log("Manage to get to here");
    console.log("dataInAction",data);
    return {
        type: Action.ADD_DYNAMIC,
        payload: data
    }

}
```

Comment: please consider to upvote and accept the answer if you like .. thank you